# ng-show/ng-hide loops when a "submit()" added, making the browser crash

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I am trying to add an error message with an either ng-show or ng-hide.

```
<p ng-show="submit()">Incorrect login/password.</p>

<form method="POST" name="adminform" ng-submit="submit()" class="admin-login-form">

    <label for="username">Admin Login</label>
    <input ng-model="username" type="text" name="username" class="form-control" required autofocus="yes"/>

    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input ng-model="password" type="password" name="password" class="form-control" required />

    <input type="submit" class="form-control" name="submit" value="Login" required/>

</form>
```

Ideally, the show/hide needs to be activated when submit() was run and did not succeed on login. However, when I do ng-show="submit()" it works but keeps refreshing itself and looping, making the browser crash and giving an error in the console even if the submit button itself hasn't been clicked.

```
$scope.submit = function() {
                  var data = {
                      'username': $scope.username,
                      'password': $scope.password
                  };

                  var hookphp = loginService.login();

                  hookphp.save(data,
                      function(result){
                          $location.path("dashboard");
                      },

                      function(){
                          alert('Invalid password/login.');

                      }
                  );
              };
```

Also, it never gives me the alert when the login is not successful. Could anyone suggest how to do this properly? I am still in the process of figuring out how Javascript and Angular work. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<p ng-show="errorVisible">Incorrect login/password.</p>
```

In angular

```
$scope.errorVisible = true/false (set it whenever you need it)
```

So:

```
$scope.errorVisible = false;
$scope.submit = function() {
              var data = {
                  'username': $scope.username,
                  'password': $scope.password
              };

              var hookphp = loginService.login();

              hookphp.save(data,
                  function(result){
                      $location.path("dashboard");
                      $scope.errorVisible = false; //optional
                  },
                  function(){
                      $scope.errorVisible = true;
                  }
              );
          };
```

Also the reason it's looping forever in your initial code is that ng-show keeps calling the function, but the function doesn't return anything.

Comment: Awesome suggestion. I really think it would work but for some reason my function only hits the first (success) portion even if the login is wrong and never ever even gets to the fail half.... Any suggestions on that?

Comment: Ha-ha! I needed to put your recommendation into a different controller.

Answer (score 0):

On your code, it seems like your function is not returning either `true` or `false` depending on the login status, so in that case, since function call is success, the output of the function will always be `true` causing your login failure label will be visible at all times.

As @MrVentzi suggested, it is better to use separate scope variable in order to decide wheter to show the message or not. If you try to do it as

```
<p ng-show="submit()">Incorrect login/password.</p>
```

`ng-show` will be constantly calling and listening to output of the function. In order to show you better, I created this example: http://jsfiddle.net/eytt2d8x/